# Creating C++ CLR Managed DLL

Tags: .net, build, c++-cli

I have this class:

```
public ref class Database
    {
    private:
        String ^username, ^password, ^name, ^telNum, ^celNum, ^address, ^location;
        String ^tempUser;
    public:
        Database(String^, String^, String^, String^, String^, String^, String^);
        bool ifFileExists();
        bool ifAccountExists();
        void CreateAccount();
    };
```

and i defined this:

> bool Database::ifAccountExists() {    ifstream File("Database.txt",
>   ios_base::in);
>
> File >>tempUser; //this line gets error I think there is problem with
>   String^
>
> //return true or false }

How do I resolve this?

Comment: This cannot work, the native iostream classes don't know beans about managed types like System::String.  Use StreamReader::ReadLine() or File::ReadAllLines() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans pointed out, you will need to provide help to the managed side, or write the entire code with managed types, like the following:

```
bool Database::IfAccountExists()
{
    if (System::IO::File::Exists(L"Database.txt"))
    {
        array<System::String ^> ^lines = System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(L"Database.txt");
        for each(System::String ^line in lines)
        {
            array<System::String ^> ^tokens = line->Split('|');
            for each (System::String ^token in tokens)
            {
                // if found
                //    return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have another problem, I am using this code:
tempUser = MyInFile->ReadLine()->Split('|');

I get error: cannot convert from 'cli::array<System::String ^,1> ^' to ' System::String^'

Comment: It only occurs when I add the Split('|'). It is somewhat converting to another type, how can I resolve this?

Comment: The Split function will return an array of strings.  I will modify my response in hopes that will help.